# how to crawl youtube video links with a keyword search

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-crawler

I'm doing some research
I want to crawl youtube video links(and then get video IDs)

for example, if I type in keyword "obama" on youtube search bar
then youtube.com will return the resulted page

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=htc&page=2
scroll the page down to the bottom
we can see the page number 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
click on the page number from 2 to 3 to 4 to 5....
then we can reach the maximum page number :50

so I want to download all the pages from 1 to 50
there is a url trick,like

```
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=obama&page=5
```

however, if I use wget to download each page, sometimes, the downloading will be blocked
or sometimes, when the page number is big, the returned page is not a abnormal page.

so a correct way is to manually click on the page number button and use the web browser to download each page, is it possible to automate the mannual procedures?
I searched on INternet, some poeple mentioned chrome javascript extention,
anyway, are there any ways to write some automation scripts to mimic the mannual operation? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use their API? Crawling is generally bad practise.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters

> ```
> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?
>     q=football+-soccer
>     &orderby=published
>     &start-index=11
>     &max-results=10
>     &v=2
> ```

Comment: these api can't get all the video ids related to a search keyword

Comment: If there is some limitation in the API it's probably there for a reason. Can you give examples?

Comment: ah, it seems OK, but I all so want to collect the comments, like https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=FL7yD-0pqZg&page=6 , so I still hope to use automation scripts to mimic mannual operation

Comment: This? https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments

Comment: thanks, but this only provides limited number of comments, I want to collect a lot of comments